# Functions seem to be causing infinite loops?

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to create a program that will give me the number of least possible moves with any given number according to the following algorithms but I seem to be getting no where as there seems to be an infinite loop somewhere and I'm guessing it's my functions as I have only just started using them

If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated

Here is my code:

```
num = 4

x = 0

def div3(num):
    n3 = num / 3
    n3 = n3 + n3
    num = num - n3
    print("DIV3")
    return num

def div2(num):
    num = num / 2
    print("DIV2")
    return num

def min1(num):
    num = num - 1
    print("MIN1")
    return num

while num != 0:

    if num / 3 % 1 == 0:
        div3(num)
        x = x + 1
        print(x)
    elif num / 2 % 1 == 0:
        div2(num)
        x = x + 1
        print(x)
    else:
        min1(num)
        x = x + 1
        print(x)

print(x)
```

Comment: You haven't assigned num in the global scope to the new value. Change `div3(num)` to `num = div3(num)`.

Comment: You `return` a value from a function but you never use it on the call site. Try doing `num = div2(num)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do, but the expressions like this one do not make much sense:

```
num / 3 % 1
```

An int divided by the int 3 always gives an int, and any int modulo 1 is always zero.

Maybe you meant this?

```
(num / 3.0) % 1    # Also adding parens for clarity.
```

Also, the outer `num` variable will never change. Maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
num = div3(num)
```

I would suggest that you put the outer code inside a function too. That will help to clarify that the outer `num` is not the same as the `num` inside your `div()` functions. So your program would have a structure like this:

```
def div3(num):
    ...

def div2(num):
    ...

def min1(num):
    ...

def main():
    num = 4
    x = 0
    while num != 0:
        ...
        num = div(...)
        ...

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def div3(num):
n3 = num / 3
n3 = n3 + n3
num = num - n3
print("DIV3")
return num
```

First of all num can't be changed inside the function as the scope of num is local to function, so make it as global and change the parameter for the function to some other variable say "value" else local and global variable will conflicts. Sample change

```
def div3(value):
n3 = value / 3
n3 = n3 + n3
global num
num = value - n3
print("DIV3")
return num
```

Next fix the issue with your loop, the loop will go to infinite loop after the first iteration. when num=2 the loop will go to infinite as `num = value - n3` always gives out 2 so it keeps on executing the function DIV3